# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing, recursion, stack-overflow

I am making a Minesweeper clone for the purpose of teaching myself swing and understanding java more in general. I am almost entirely finished with it, except that I cannot get the cascading method to work correctly.

I understand that my error is in my recursion, but I can't seem to understand how to stop it. The best I can get is to stop the method after 1 iteration, but it really needs to cascade across the board.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at bombSweeper.BombSweeper.getField(BombSweeper.java:1168)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
at bombSweeper.Bomb.check(Bomb.java:316)
```

The line numbers are always referring to a recursive call in the code below, and it changes depending on where the button is in my minefield.

```
package bombSweeper;

import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Bomb extends JButton implements MouseListener {

int imageNumber, index, defusedCheck;

boolean isBomb, isChecked, isFlagged;

private ImageIcon bomb = new ImageIcon("./imgs/bomb.png"),
                  flag = new ImageIcon("./imgs/flag.png"),
                  one = new ImageIcon("./imgs/1.png"),
                  two = new ImageIcon("./imgs/2.png"),
                  three = new ImageIcon("./imgs/3.png"),
                  four = new ImageIcon("./imgs/4.png"),
                  five = new ImageIcon("./imgs/5.png"),
                  six = new ImageIcon("./imgs/6.png"),
                  seven = new ImageIcon("./imgs/7.png"),
                  eight = new ImageIcon("./imgs/8.png");

public Bomb(int index) {

    isBomb = false;
    isChecked = false;
    isFlagged = false;

    imageNumber = 0;        
    this.index = index;

    addMouseListener(this);
    setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setFocusPainted(false);

}

public boolean isBomb() {

    return isBomb;

}

public void setBomb() {

    isBomb = true;
    imageNumber = 9;

}

public void setCount(int adjBombs) {

    imageNumber = adjBombs;

}

public void flag() {

    if(!isFlagged) {

        this.setIcon(flag);

    } else {

        this.setIcon(null);
    }

    isFlagged ^= true;

}

public void check() {

    if(isFlagged || isChecked) {

        return;

    }

    if(isBomb) {

        detonate();
        return;

    }

    if(imageNumber != 0) {

        if(imageNumber == 1) {

            this.setIcon(one);

        } else if(imageNumber == 2) {

            this.setIcon(two);

        } else if(imageNumber == 3) {

            this.setIcon(three);

        } else if(imageNumber == 4) {

            this.setIcon(four);

        } else if(imageNumber == 5) {

            this.setIcon(five);

        } else if(imageNumber == 6) {

            this.setIcon(six);

        } else if(imageNumber == 7) {

            this.setIcon(seven);

        } else if(imageNumber == 8) {

            this.setIcon(eight);

        }

        isChecked = true;

    }

    if(imageNumber == 0) {

        this.setEnabled(false);

        if(index == 0) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);

        } else if(index > 0 && index < 9) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);


        } else if(index == 9) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);              

        } else if(index % 10 == 0 && index != 140) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);  

        } else if((index - 9) % 10 == 0 && index != 149) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);

        } else if(index == 140) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);

        } else if (index > 140 && index < 149) { 

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);

        } else if(index == 149) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);

        } else {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);              

        }

    }

}

public void check(Bomb bobomb) {

    if(isFlagged || isChecked) {

        return;

    }

    if(imageNumber != 0) {

        if(imageNumber == 1) {

            this.setIcon(one);

        } else if(imageNumber == 2) {

            this.setIcon(two);

        } else if(imageNumber == 3) {

            this.setIcon(three);

        } else if(imageNumber == 4) {

            this.setIcon(four);

        } else if(imageNumber == 5) {

            this.setIcon(five);

        } else if(imageNumber == 6) {

            this.setIcon(six);

        } else if(imageNumber == 7) {

            this.setIcon(seven);

        } else if(imageNumber == 8) {

            this.setIcon(eight);

        }

        isChecked = true;

    } else if(imageNumber == 0) {

        if(index == 0) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);

        } else if(index > 0 && index < 9) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);


        } else if(index == 9) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);              

        } else if(index % 10 == 0 && index != 140) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);  

        } else if((index - 9) % 10 == 0 && index != 149) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);

        } else if(index == 140) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);

        } else if (index > 140 && index < 149) { 

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);

        } else if(index == 149) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);

        } else {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 11]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index - 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 9]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);              

        }

    }       

}

public void detonate() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {

        BombSweeper.getField()[i].isChecked = true;

        if(BombSweeper.getField()[i].isBomb) {

            BombSweeper.getField()[i].setIcon(bomb);

        }

    }

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    if(!isChecked) {


        if(e.getButton() == 1) {

            check();

        }

        if(e.getButton() == 3) {

            flag();

        }

    }

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}

}
```

The BombSweeper class constructs my board and the call to it returns the array of bombs I've made. It is an array of Bomb objects that is 150 elements long.

Any ideas on how to stop this overflow would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to set an indicator for “already processed” on the field *before* going into recursion. At the moment you are *not* setting the `isChecked` flag when `imageNumber == 0`. But you are setting `enabled` to `false` so you could change the first line of the method to `if(isFlagged || isChecked || !isEnabled()) return;`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just went and made that alteration, and it results in a situation like I had before. It stops the infinite recursion, but it only checks at max 1 cell. I'm afraid I might have to completely rework my check method again. Lol, I hope the 7th time is the charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to debug this, I would do some experimentation with printing to the console to figure out where my logic error is. I'd do something like this:

```
public void check() {
    System.out.println("Checking location index = " + index);
    // Some code omitted
    if(imageNumber == 0) {

        System.out.println("Location number " + index + " has no bombs surrounding it.");

        this.setEnabled(false);

        if(index == 0) {

            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 1]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 10]);
            check(BombSweeper.getField()[index + 11]);

        } else if(index > 0 && index < 9) {
            // Remaining Code omitted
}
```

As some other thoughts, the code might be easier to read if you were to use a 2 dimensional array. Then you could index into x,y locations directly instead of doing clever array slicing.

Finally, you might consider writing some unit tests that explore the problem. I'd start with a 1 by 1 grid with no bombs and see what the 'check' method does. That might make the problem clear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That's a good starting point to go off of. I did start with a 2D array on my first few iterations, but I was having even worse luck. :S